# How can I prevent all Null values from being returned in this TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, isnull

I've got this TSQL:

```
SELECT Invd.Unit, M.MemberName, Invd.Description
FROM InvoiceDetail Invd
LEFT JOIN Members M on Invd.MemberNo = M.MemberNo
GROUP BY Invd.Unit, M.MemberName, Invd.Description
```

...which works well for 90% of what's returned (aside from being agonizingly slow), but approximately 10% of the returned records contain a Null value for either Invd.Unit or M.MemberName or both.

I only want records with no Nulls anywhere. What do I need to do to prevent records with any null values from being returned in the result set?

I don't want to use something like this:

```
SELECT IsNull(Invd.Unit, 'no Unit'), IsNull(M.MemberName, 'no Member Name'), Invd.Description
. . .
```

I just don't want those records at all; I just want unique/distinct combinations of those three fields (excluding nulls in any of them - the data is only useful where all three values exist).

Comment: If you're not actually calculating aggregate values then `DISTINCT` would be much clearer here than the `GROUP BY`, IMO.

Comment: No, there's no calculating going on; just a list of unique combinations of those three fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `LEFT Join` to `INNER Join` with `Where` condition

```
SELECT Invd.unit, 
       M.membername, 
       Invd.description 
FROM   invoicedetail Invd 
       INNER JOIN members M 
               ON Invd.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  Invd.unit IS NOT NULL 
       AND M.membername IS NOT NULL 
       AND Invd.description IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY Invd.unit, 
          M.membername, 
          Invd.description
```

As mentioned in comments it is better to use `Distinct` instead of `Group by` which will make the intention clear. When there is no *Aggregate* in `Select` the Sql server is smart enough to convert the `group by` to `distinct`

Comment: I guess `Group By` is used here to remove duplicates

Comment: @VR46: Claro que si.

Comment: I thought a DISTINCT() could only be done on one column.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon DISTINCT applies to rows, not individual columns.